# Array has 10 objects representing players and I'm trying to loop over and display the 5 players from team 1 in Vue.js. Am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

`this.match.details.participants` contains an array with 10 objects which represent players. Each player has a property `teamId` which is used to determine if he's on the first or second team. I'm trying to loop over all participants and display the first team in 1 column on the page, and the second team on the 2 column on the page.

I've mostly figured it out, but I'm curious if my implementation is alright and if there are better alternatives. Currently I've done it this way:

```
<div v-for='friendly in friendlyTeam'>
    {{ friendly }}
</div>
<div v-for='enemy in enemyTeam'>
    {{ enemy }}
</div>

data(){
    return {
        match: null
    }
},
computed: {
    friendlyTeam(){
        let friendlyTeamId = this.match.mainParticipant.teamId; // id is either 100 or 200
        let friendlyTeam = this.match.details.participants.filter(value => value.teamId === friendlyTeamId);

        return friendlyTeam;
    },
    enemyTeam(){
        let enemyTeamId = 0;
        let friendlyTeamId = this.match.mainParticipant.teamId; // id is either 100 or 200
        if (friendlyTeamId == 100) {
            enemyTeamId = 200
        } else if (friendlyTeamId == 200) {
            enemyTeamId = 100
        }
        let enemyTeam = this.match.details.participants.filter(value => value.teamId === enemyTeamId );

        return enemyTeam;
    }
}
```

This return an array of 5 objects that represent the players on the friendly team. This works fine and dandy, however, it seems like I'd have to copy and paste the entire computed property and alter it a bit in order to get the enemy team as well which will break the DRY principle.

Are there any better alternatives to what I've done? Is using a computed property to extract only the objects which I want and then loop over them a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor a bit.

```
if (friendlyTeamId == 100) {
        let enemyTeamId == 200
    } else if (friendlyTeamId == 200) {
        let enemyTeamId == 100
 }
```

Change to:

```
let enemyTeamId = friendlyTeamId === 100 ? 200 : 100
```